# Firebase returned value not rendering in ejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase-realtime-database, ejs

In my ejs i have this code:

```
 <% for(var bill in ChildData){ %>
    <tr>
       <td><%= bill.id %></td>
       <td><%= bill.Phone %></td>
       <td><%= bill.Amount %></td> 
       <td><%= bill.Purchase_Date %></td>
       <td>View Details</td>
    </tr>
 <% } %>
```

In my node I have

```
app.get("/viewbill", function(req,res){
    database.once("value", function (snapshot) {
        res.render('viewbills', {ChildData: snapshot.val()});    
    });
})
```

However on the page I obtain
[Screenshot of the output I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6QOp.png)

Even if I try I get the same result

```
<td><%- JSON.stringify(bill.id) %></td>
```

Comment: have you tried `console.log(snapshot.val())` before `res.render`

Comment: Yes i did try console.log(snapshot.val()) and I got the value but it just doesn't render in ejs.

Comment: how about console.log inside the ejs to make sure

Comment: Yes it displays the data in terminal when i use console.lo inside ejs

Comment: can you post a ss of it. i have no clue whats wrong

Comment: This is it https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6QOp.png

Comment: can you also share a ss of terminal console log

Comment: This is the screenshot of the terminal https://i.stack.imgur.com/7X0VE.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing ejs code to this gave me the output

```
<% Object.keys(ChildData).forEach(function(key) { %>
                <tr>
                    <td><%- ChildData[key].id %></td>
                    <td><%- ChildData[key].Phone %></td>
                    <td><%- ChildData[key].Amount %></td> 
                    <td><%- ChildData[key].Purchase_Date %></td>
                    <td>View Details</td>
                </tr>
              <% }); %>
```